# Количество компонент связности

Tags: c++, графы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    int n, m, k, mas[4][4];
    int cur = 0;

    cin>>n>>m;

    vector <int> was(n, -1);
    queue <int> q;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cin>>mas[i][j];
        } 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (was[i] != -1)
           continue;
        q.push(i);
        while (!q.empty())
        {
              int v = q.front();
              q.pop();
              if (was[v] != -1)
                 continue;
              was[v] = cur;
              for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                  if (mas[i][j] != 0 && was[j] == -1)
                     q.push(j);
        }
        cur++;
    }
    cout<<cur;
}
```

Данный код считает максимальную компоненту связности. Как найти их количество?
Например,

```
3   
0 0 0  
0 0 1  
0 1 0
```

Эта программа выводит 3, а количество будет равно 2.

Comment: а почему 1 а не 2 для начала?

Comment: @pavel да вы правы, ошиблась

Comment: @pavel, поможете, как это сделать?

Comment: да код в целом работать должен. Хотя и странный он. Полностью в сборе решение покажите, может вы читаете не правильно.

Comment: @pavel изменила

Comment: @pavel как я поняла, нужно выбрать первую вершину графа, отметить её и все связанные с ней точки (прямо или чрез другие вершины). Получается первая компонента. Выбрать следующую непомеченную вершину графа, от неё получаем вторую компоненту и т.д., пока не останется непомеченных вершин. Но у меня проблема с кодом. Можете помочь?

Comment: 1 опечатку я нашёл. `if (mas[i][j] != 0 ` => `if (mas[v][j] != 0 ` А 2 опечатка - вы зачем m читаете?!